# Powershell 5.0 / ISE

Tags: powershell

I have an example code snippet that suggests using

```
(Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.WorkingSet64 -gt 20mb}).Count
```

to return the count of all processess using > 20Mb.

It works, but when typing, neither Intellisense or the "Tab" key shows this property, rather they show the properties of an individual process - which I find misleading.

I understand, that specifying an item property will give me the list of that property only, but is there a way to easily see, in general, what ALL the valid propeties are, including list aggregates etc?

Even assigning to a variable

```
$processes = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.WorkingSet64 -gt 20mb}
```

does not show me "Count" as a valid property of `$processes` until AFTER the assignment has been actually run and the value assigned - when writing the script it still shows the properties for an individual item.

For me, Intellisense / Tab help that does not cover all the options kind of defeats the purpose ... (not having to remember hundreds objects/functions and their properties / parameters).

Is there any way to improve this situation? Some syntax trick have I missed?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to find out all of the properties of an object is to pipe the output to `Get-Member`:

```
Get-Process | Get-Member
```

Sometimes there are hidden properties and methods that can only be seen if you add the `-force` switch:

```
Get-Process | Get-Member -Force
```

The `count` property is an automatic property that is always usable on any collection object but that isn't explicitly listed as a property. Another example of an automatic property is `length`.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I wasn't clear. I don't want to return a list of the properties as a result, I want to see what the possible options are *whilst coding*, Without having to "just know", or run test code to find out. eg I want Intellisense or double-tab options to show me the valid options. I have been a C# programmer for the past 13 years, so I have been used to this sort of help for ... quite a while! It is absolutely a learning and productivity aid par exellence. If Powershell only does a half-assed implementation of it, I think I find that worse than none(where at least you know where you stand!)

Comment: As you've seen, intellisense will return all the properties of the object, with the exception of automatic ones like `count` and `length` which you just need to remember are always available.

Comment: I've started a chat for this FYI: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/142251/powershell-5-0-ise-intellisense

Answer (score 2):

Using    `@()` to force an array type is handy when that is what is wanted.

e.g. `$processes = @(Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.WorkingSet64 -gt 20mb}).` will show you "Count" and the other array properties.

Other than that, let's say the Intellisense has various limitations / shortcomings that I will just have to learn... sigh.